# How can I prompt user to upload file from within a PrimeNG menuItem in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-menu

I have a menu item like this

```
 items = [{
            label: 'Upload', icon: 'pi pi-plus', command: (event) => { //get the event.target.file and pass it into a service that will manage the rest},
...
        }]
```

So in the Html I am using the `<p-menu>` like this

```
<p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
```

And all the labels and icons are being displayed correctly. But how do I get the upload to open a prompt for file upload like a `<input type='file'>` so that I can get the event.target.file to pass to the service being called in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research goes there is no feature in PrimeNg that makes this easier.
Inorder to prompt the user for a file upload I had to create an input file type and then get the files after calling the click() event on it

So in the menuItem I call the prompt which then calls the service.

`items = [{label: 'Upload', icon: 'pi pi-plus', command: () => {upload_prompt( )}]`

```
upload_prompt( ): void {

        const input = document.createElement( 'input' );
        input.type = 'file';
        input.multiple = true;

        input.onchange = () => {
            let file = input.files as FileList;
            file_upload_service( file )
        }
        input.click()
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.